# How does one access Facebook Ads via connect.facebook.net/.../sdk.js?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have the following elements:

- a facebook account
- an App set up in developers.facebook.com (and added it to my user)
- my own website on my server

In my website I implement via Javascript

```js
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXX', // here  my App Id
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.9'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
};
```

That works fine and I can eg make calls like

```js
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r) {
  if(r.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/ZZZZZ/campaigns',function(response)  {
      // do something!
      console.log(response); // (§)
    });
  }
});
```

I get the following output at (§):

`{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'ZZZZZ' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,“fbtrace_id":“#########"}}`

Here XXXX = my App Id, and ZZZZZ = my Business Account Id. They all definitely exist! And as the user that set it all up, my up until that stage logged in user should have all the necessary permissions.

What is going on? How do I make this work?

If you know, please try to provide me concrete code. (All the guides online that I have found are frustratingly vague, which is the reason I am posting this question here.) Thanks in advance!

**Further Question:** does `//connect.facebook.net/.../sdk.js` suffice in geneneral to interface with Business Manager via my Api? Or Do I need to download this strange Javascript API SDK und use require, and all that horribly messy stuff?

Comment: Obviously I have read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api But that does not help me either my error or with the setup. It provides piecemeal explanations, that work isolated, but not together.

Comment: The user needs to grant the app the necessary permission(s) to access this kind of data first ...

Comment: Yes, but how? When logging the user in (with the recommended HTML Facebook button) I include `'ads_management,ads_read,manage_pages,publish_actions’` as my permissions parameter. (I used `<fb:login-button scope='(afore mentioned)' onlogin='checkloginstatus();'></fb:login-button>`, where `checkloginstatus` is a function set up exactly as in the documentation. That all works fine.)

Comment: And the user is an admin or developer of the app?

Comment: Verify what permissions the user has granted, by debugging the access token, or via a call to `/me/permissions`

Comment: I’ll try this. Hold on. `{"data":[{"permission":"email","status":"granted"},{"permission":"publish_actions","status":"granted"},{"permission":"manage_pages","status":"granted"},{"permission":"pages_show_list","status":"granted"},{"permission":"ads_management","status":"granted"},{"permission":"ads_read","status":"granted"},{"permission":"business_management","status":"granted"},{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"}]}`

Comment: I’m starting to think, the object does not exist… which is odd. I generated the campaigns to experiment with, and haven’t added any payment methods. Maybe Facebook is blocking them. *Confirmed:* (sadly) in Graph-API (directly) I called the account Id. The response ‘Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'ZZZZZ' does not exist’ : (

Comment: You get that same message if the object does exist, but you are not allowed to see it (due to missing permissions, or other restrictions). Did you chose your own app id in Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I chose my API. I had to add the account number to the list of authorised accounts in the advanced settings (and I did it in an added product—Marketing API). Then it worked. I have now tried to reproduce the error, by removing these authorisations… and oddly it still works! This is really frustrating. I want to know what turns this error on and off.